# Have to use instance variable in sessions_controller.rb to pass tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

Doing the Hartl Rails tutorial sample app.  His sessions_controller.rb uses local variables, but in order to pass the tests, I have to convert them to instance variables.  Am I screwing something else up?

My sessions_controller.rb:

```
    class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new

  end

  def create
    @user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if @user && @user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      if @user.activated?
        log_in @user
        params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(@user) : forget(@user)
        redirect_back_or @user
      else
        message = "Account not activated. "
        message += "Check your email for the activation link."
        flash[:warning] = message
        redirect_to root_url
      end
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    log_out if logged_in?
    redirect_to root_url
  end

end
```

Replace @user with user to get the Hartl version.

The specific test that fails from the users_login_test.rb:

```
  test "login with remembering" do
    log_in_as(@user, remember_me: '1')
    assert_equal cookies['remember_token'], assigns(:user).remember_token
  end
```

The use of the instance variable in the test is from Hartl, not me.

The specific error generated is this:

```
ERROR["test_login_with_remembering", UsersLoginTest, 1.3149604040081613]
 test_login_with_remembering#UsersLoginTest (1.31s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `remember_token' for nil:NilClass
            test/integration/users_login_test.rb:43:in `block in <class:UsersLoginTest>'
```

Comment: What error(s) are you getting when you use the code as per Hartl's tutorial? (note: edit your question and add it there as formatting in comments is harder to read and it should be part of your original question) :)

Comment: Added the error message, thanks.

Comment: Right... so `assigns(:user)` is blank because assigns basically looks for `@-variables` but you probably don't need to use the user in assigns to figure out the remember-token... wouldn't there be one in `@user` (in your test, as opposed to @user in your controller)? Try `assert_equal cookies['remember_token'], @user.remember_token` and see what happens?

Comment: Actually I think the sessions_controller.rb is supposed to use the instance variables.  https://www.railstutorial.org/book/_single-page#code-login_create_user_instance
Guess later versions of the file don't show the answer to the exercise, but that makes it very confusing.